# Calculate retention rate for the users per time window in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to calculate the user retention for the users per time window without comparing the previous time windows.

For example,

Table:

```
let T = datatable(UserId:string, Timestamp:datetime)
[
    // May
    'A', datetime(2022-05-01),
    'D', datetime(2022-05-06),
    'C', datetime(2022-05-10),
    'B', datetime(2022-05-15),
    'E', datetime(2022-05-20),
    // June
    'C', datetime(2022-06-02),
    'T', datetime(2022-06-02),
    'J', datetime(2022-06-02),
    'H', datetime(2022-06-13),
    'T', datetime(2022-06-13),
    'G', datetime(2022-06-15),
    'B', datetime(2022-06-15),
    'S', datetime(2022-06-18),
    'M', datetime(2022-06-18),
    'L', datetime(2022-06-20),
    'Z', datetime(2022-06-25),
    // July
    'C', datetime(2022-07-04),
    'T', datetime(2022-07-04),
    'M', datetime(2022-07-04),
    'G', datetime(2022-07-10),
    'L', datetime(2022-07-10)
];
```

For

```
start = datetime(2022-05-01)\
end = datetime(2022-08-01)\
time window = 28d
```

Result Expected:

| From | To | Retained | RetentionRate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01T00:00:00Z | 2022-05-01T00:00:00Z | 5 | 1 |
| 2022-05-01T00:00:00Z | 2022-05-29T00:00:00Z | 2 | 0.4 |
| 2022-05-01T00:00:00Z | 2022-06-26T00:00:00Z | 1 | 0.2 |
| 2022-05-01T00:00:00Z | 2022-07-24T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-05-29T00:00:00Z | 2022-05-29T00:00:00Z | 10 | 1 |
| 2022-05-29T00:00:00Z | 2022-06-26T00:00:00Z | 5 | 0.5 |
| 2022-05-29T00:00:00Z | 2022-07-24T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-06-26T00:00:00Z | 2022-06-26T00:00:00Z | 5 | 1 |
| 2022-06-26T00:00:00Z | 2022-07-24T00:00:00Z | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-07-24T00:00:00Z | 2022-07-24T00:00:00Z | 0 | NaN |

The user journey starts from the current window and checks if the user was retained in the next window. May 1 started with 5 users and only 2 were retained in the next time window and only 1 was retained in the next. May 29 started with 10 users (including 1 user already seen in May) and in the next window 5 were retained.

Kusto has [new_activity_metrics plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/new-activity-metrics-plugin) but it takes into account the previous time window.

In the above case, From June to June window will filter the users who were already seen in May.

One solution I can think of is to use `new_activity_metrics` and call set each month as the start value.

```
T
| evaluate new_activity_metrics(UserId, Timestamp, datetime(2022-05-01), datetime(2022-08-01), 28d ) 
| where from_Timestamp == datetime(2022-05-01)
| union (
    T
    | evaluate new_activity_metrics(UserId, Timestamp, datetime(2022-05-29), datetime(2022-08-01), 28d ) 
    | where from_Timestamp == datetime(2022-05-29)
)
| union ( 
    T
    | evaluate new_activity_metrics(UserId, Timestamp, datetime(2022-06-26), datetime(2022-08-01), 28d ) 
    | where from_Timestamp == datetime(2022-06-26)
)
| union ( 
    T
    | evaluate new_activity_metrics(UserId, Timestamp, datetime(2022-07-24), datetime(2022-08-01), 28d ) 
    | where from_Timestamp == datetime(2022-07-24)
)
| project from_Timestamp, to_Timestamp, dcount_retained_values, retention_rate
```

Not sure how to make this dynamic ( work for any given start and end time )

Probably there is a better plugin to use that I'm missing.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Any reason your *From* and *To* are not actual dates or at least sortable strings e.g., date in yyyy-MM format?

Comment: In addition to the required results please provide a matching sample data in datatable / CSV format.

Comment: Added the actual datetime, sample datatable, and the result. Also added real query that I used instead of pseudocode.

Comment: I don't see how the sample data is related to the results, e.g., what special about `2022-05-29`?

Comment: Since the window here is 28d, 2022-05-29 is 28days from 2022-05-01. Does that answer your question?

Comment: You can run the query that I have provided in the question and get the results table.

Comment: To union multiple tabular expressions, simply use `| union (...), (...), (...)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250322/discussion-between-naresh-kumar-and-david--markovitz).

Comment: According to your example *start* should be `2022-05-01`

Comment: Yes. You are right. I have fixed the start in the question to be `2022-05-01`